# Visual Studio 2019で単体テストを作成できない

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Visual Studio 2019において、下記のようなクラスのメソッドについて単体テストを作成できない。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

このプロジェクトは、単体テスト用のプロジェクトではなく、.NET Core3.1のWinFormsのプロジェクト（non-test project）かつpublicなクラスのpublicなメソッドにもかかわらず、上記のエラーが出て単体テストを生成できません。
生成するにはどのようにすればよろしいでしょうか。

追記：
プロジェクトの参照先のプロジェクトが（意図せず）単体テストプロジェクトを参照していたため、参照元のプロジェクトも単体テストプロジェクトと認識されているため、単体テストを作成できませんでした。無事解決いたしました。

Comment: 情報としては直ぐには見つかりませんが、何かとバッティングしていそうな短く一般的なメソッド名を変えてみてはどうでしょう？ [dotnet test](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test) あるいは`void`で戻り値が無いとか引数も無いのが良くないとか？

Comment: 一応画像にあるクラスとメソッドを作成して試しています。バッティング等はないと思っています。また、下記コメントの通り、同一構成で新規作成して試したところ、問題なく動作したので、おそらく参照などの設定になにか問題があるのかもしれません。少し調べてみます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

私の環境(Windows10 64bit Visual Studio Professional 2019)では再現せず、問題なくテストが実行できてしまいます。
しかし[本家SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44399000)の質問のコメント上で、同様に回答者の環境では再現しないやり取りがされていました。
こちらはVS2015ですが、結局質問者は「ソリューションを作り直してコードを貼り付けたらエラーが解消した」とのことでした。
コメント末尾で類似のエラーが起こった人から「テストフレームワークの参照を外したら直った」という報告もありました。

以下は上記の回答と[外部サイト](https://teratail.com/questions/116470)から得られた**一般的な**対処法とTipsです。
@matarimocha さんの役には立たないとは思います(ごめんなさい)が、検索してここにたどり着いた方向けの確認事項として追記します。

- クラスとメソッドはpublicですか？
- プロパティ単体クラスのテストはできません。

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    //publicじゃない
    class Class1
    {
        public void Test() { }
    }
    public class Class2
    {
        //メソッドがない
        public string HogeProperty { get { return "hoge"; } }
        public int Fuga;
    }
}
```

なお"Create Unit Tests is supported only on a non-test project and within a public class or public method."のエラーメッセージについて、
日本語環境では「単体テストの作成は、パブリック クラスかパブリック メソッド内の非テスト プロジェクトでのみサポートされます。」というエラーメッセージになります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
一応画像の通り、publicかつメソッドを対象としています。
（画像のメソッドを右クリックして作成を試みました）
また、試しに同一構成で新規作成したプロジェクトでは問題なく行なえました。参照などの設定に一部問題があるのかもしれません。テスト関係は特に参照していないですが、もう一度プロジェクトを作り直してみるなど、いろいろ試してみます。
あと、言語環境は都合上英語になっていました。わざわざ日本語での表記ありがとうございます。

Comment: すみません、参照先のプロジェクトに誤って単体テストプロジェクトが参照されていました。対象のプロジェクトがテストプロジェクトでなくとも、参照に入っているとだめなのですね…。無事解決しました、ありがとうございました。